# Bootstrap issue on Nokia Lumia

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing a website using [Bootstrap-v3](http://www.getbootstrap.com) and [Backstretch](http://www.srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/), example **[here](http://www.guglie.altervista.org/Fun%20e%20Rude/)**.
It works with every device except with Windows Phone, I have no navbar, no background and only the title text.
I tried using the fix suggested [here](http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html#the-fix) but I got the same result.

Do you know how to fix this problem?
Is there a way to test it without having a Windows Phone?

Thanks!

Comment: To test it without having a Windows Phone, use IE and in the developer tools (F12) in the `Emulation` tab (Ctrl+8) you can choose a profile between Desktop and Windows Phone (among other options).

Comment: Plugins like Backstretch are pretty much outdated. You can just use CSS for this [`background-size: cover`](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/).

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313891/positionfixed-in-windows-phone-7