# CSS: position:fixed not working on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, html, css, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to develop a web based app for Windows Phone 8. I have a web page with two divs with the style `position:fixed`. If I open the Internet Explorer app on the Windows Phone and navigate to my web page, the fixed elements display perfectly. However, when I view the web page in the `WebBrowser` WP8 control in the native app, the `position:fixed` style is completely ignored.

I also noticed that all my css transitions also will only work in the full Internet Explorer app. This is not as big of a problem, but the lack of fixed positioning is a real issue. Why is the `WebBrowser` doing this, and are there any workarounds?

I know fixed positioning and transitions did not work in WP7, I'm wondering if maybe the WP8 `WebBrowser` control has the same code as the WP7 `WebBrowser` control.

Answer (score 5):

`position:-ms-device-fixed` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

> > **Fixed positioning**
> >
> > Elements that are positioned using CSS fixed positioning behave
> >     differently between Internet Explorer for Windows Phone OS 8.0
> >     compared to Internet Explorer for Windows Phone OS 7.1. In Internet
> >     Explorer Windows Phone OS 8.0 (as well as on the desktop), fixed
> >     elements are positioned relative to the client view of the browser
> >     window. This means that if an element is fixed in view at the bottom
> >     right corner, it will always appear fixed in view at the bottom right
> >     corner even when the user scrolls the page up, down, left, or right.
> >     On Windows Phone OS 7.1, fixed elements are positioned relative to the
> >     document itself and may not remain in view when the user scrolls the
> >     page. This means that if an element is fixed relative to the bottom
> >     right corner of a document, the user will see it only when navigating
> >     to the bottom right corner of the webpage.
>
> -[From microsoft's website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462082%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_BehaviorofFixedPositioning)

A possible workaround is,

Using a `div` container for the non-fixed content and applying `style="overflow: scroll"` and fixed size. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9633762/3222041) and [***here***](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/) for javascript-based fixed-positioning solutions.

Comment: I did read that document. The problem is I am using Windows Phone 8, so according to that document fixed elements should behave normally. Again, they do in the full browser. I might have to use your workaround scrolling is not as smooth that way.

Comment: Yes, but the scrolling is not smooth

Comment: @msbg Yes, scrolling will not look like native scrolling and thats the closest we can get. Helped??

Answer (score 0):

I was also hanging on this problem. It really seems not to be possible to create a fixed element and to position elements after every scroll looks even worse (try the jquery mobile online examples on your phone they do it this way).

I "solved" the problem by using a div container for my non fixed content with style="overflow: scroll" and fixed size. This worked for me. But scrolling in this container doesn't look like native scrolling.

Hope that helps